# Fetch data from mysql with comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

i have below mentioned table:

```
id      string    var
1       asdadf    ab
1       asdadf    ac
2       axdrtg    ar
2       axadtg    at
```

I want to fetch those records where for the same `id` we have same `string` but `var` is different.

Output

```
id      string    var
1       asdadf    ab
1       asdadf    ac
```

i have tried: `select id,string,var from table where string>1 group by id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `string`, `var`
FROM TABLE1
WHERE `id` IN
(
SELECT `id`
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY `id`, `string`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**Output**

```
id  string  var
1   asdadf  ab
1   asdadf  ac
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a09681/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` :

```
select * 
from table t
where exists (select 1 from Table 
              where id = t.id 
              group by string 
              having count(*) > 1) and
      exists (select 1 from table
              where id = t.id 
              group by var 
              having count(*) = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :

```
    select id,string,var from table where id in (select id from table group by string having count(id)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
select id count(*) as i,string count(*) as c from table
      group by string having c > 1 && i > 1
                     order by c desc
```